# Putting words like who and where together

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

In my text book I have a sentence I’m glad I came across. I’m not sure if Iv translated it correctly but if I have I’m happy I found this!
「いつ誰と来て何を食べたか覚えてない」
Does this mean “when and who I came with and what we ate, I can’t remember”
If you put いつ誰と来ましたか would this mean when and who did you come with?
Thank you!

Comment: Your understanding is correct. But for English I think I'd reorder the words in the translations somewhat: "I can't remember what we ate or when, or who we came with" and "When did you arrive, and who with?" (for purists: "...with whom", and similarly for the preceding)

Answer (score 1):

The words aren't actually combined. Instead, all that's happened is that the question words are put where their answers would normally be. For example, if I did suddenly remember that yesterday I came and ate pizza with Satomi, then I could say

昨日さとみさんと来てピザを食べた。

It's the same sentence structure, but instead of question words like いつ and 誰 it has concrete answers. In particular, there's no particle after 昨日 so it does "run on" into the next word.

Comment: An accurate answer... but was OP *asking* about run-on words?